# How to get distinct information from table

Tags: sql

Guys I have the following table called products the columns names are:

```
Product_ID
Category_ID
Product_Name
Brand
Quantity
Price
```

I suck a sql queries, but I need a query that I can use to obtain all products with Brand= "something" but I don't want duplicates because a product can be in more than one Category_ID
i tried the following but it did not work.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Brand="Crystal Clear"
GROUP BY Category_ID
HAVING count(Product_Name)=1
```

Comment: Not very good data structure, because it has duplicated data, anyway query with `distinct` as @realnumber3013 suggests will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming duplicate products have matching `Product_ID`s

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product_ID, Product_Name, Quantity, Price 
FROM products 
WHERE Brand="Crystal Clear"
```

may give you the data you want, but if you have any control over the structure of your database, I would strongly encourage you to get rid of the `Category_ID` column entirely and replace it with a relationship set, so you're not duplicating `products` rows just to get the same product in multiple categories. The process of removing the possibility of duplication from table structures is called normalization, for which [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a decent primer.

---

From comments on other answers, I've inferred that the OP's `Product_ID` column is a unique primary key, and duplicate products in different categories can only be identified by matching `Product_Name`, which would make the query a little more complicated

```
SELECT Product_Name, SUM(Quantity), MAX(Price)
FROM products
WHERE Brand="Crystal Clear"
GROUP BY Product_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, product_name
FROM products
WHERE Brand="Crystal Clear"
```

Comment: I used this but I got 29 rows returned and that is the same # of rows when using the query "SELECT * FROM products WHERE Brand="Crystal Clear" "

Comment: Ok remove product_id field from query and add another fields by product!

Comment: Yeah the table is poorly structured and sadly to say that I am the one who created it. I tried another query SELECT DISTINCT Product_Name FROM products WHERE Brand= "Crystal Clear" same result. I need to restructure my table. with minimum changes because of time constriants. I need to allow products to be in more than one category_id.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with `SELECT DISTINCT` as @realnumber3012 did, however you could use grouping:

```
SELECT product_id, product_name
FROM products
WHERE Brand="Crystal Clear"
GROUP BY Product_id, product_name
```